# Using scale bar in QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis-2.8, atlas, scale-bar

I'm working with qgis 2.8 (windows).

I am able to generate maps using qgis atlas. But i have a problem with the scale bar.

When i generate atlas with "fix scale" setting (1:35.000 for instance), the scale length changes for each "slide", each exported map.

Could you tell me why?

I hoped to solve the problem using "predefined method". In vain.

Below are two screenshots showing my problem :

[image]

[image]

Comment: What CRS is your map in?

Comment: Hello. The CRS EPSG of my project is 2154 (French lambert 93).It seems that the bug has been already notified : hub.qgis.org/issues/8995 The ticket seems to be closed 2 months ago. But, on my side (qgis 2.8.1), the bug is not fixed...